# Не меняется текст!

Tags: java, android

Код ошибки:

> 10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones.game$1.run(game.java:39)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   10-22 15:35:48.055 21698-21698/com.develope.vladimir.devilsbones E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Сам код:

```
public class game extends Activity {
ImageButton imageButton5;
TextView textView3;
TextView textView4;
TextView textview5;
Timer timer;
Handler handler;
Runnable tadada;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    handler = new Handler() ;
    tadada = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            final int pS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            final int cS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
            textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS);
            textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
            if (pS < cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победил компьютер!Повезёт в следующий раз!");
            } else {
                textview5.setText("Вы выиграли!Поздравляю!");
            }
            if (pS == cS) {
                textview5.setText("Победила дружба;)");

            }
        }
    };
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    timer = new Timer();
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    imageButton5.setEnabled(false);
    handler.postDelayed(tadada, 2000);
}
}
```

Смысл в том,что при нажатии на кнопку текст должен поменяться через определенное время(2 секунды),но оно не меняется и выбивает ошибку!

Comment: У вас NullPointerException  в 39 строке

Comment: Как исправить?Вродё всё обозначено, TextView3 & TextView4 & textview5 найдены по их R.id..

Comment: Для начала я не знаю где в вашем коде 39 строка, т.к. не вижу вашего кода только логи. Во вторых см. мой ответ ниже.

Comment: И не надо задавать подряд 3 одинаковых вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

```
textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
```

Все  эти 4 переменных равны null, потому что они идет перед этими строками, а не после:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```